# Increase tablet container size in Semantic UI and rebuild it

Tags: css, less, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI on a website and it looks pretty well in all the resolutions, but I'd like that, when in tablet size, the containers were a bit wider.

I've found that the variables that control that width are in the file `themes/default/elements/container.variables`. I read that, to avoid modifying the original files, you have to edit the file `site/globals/site.variables`, so I've added the following lines:

```
@blue  : #00709e;   
@green : #75912b;
@black : #464646;

@tabletWidth: (@tabletBreakpoint+201) - (@tabletMinimumGutter * 2) - @scrollbarWidth;
```

I've rebuilt the CSS/JS files using gulp and I can see that the blue, green and black colors have changed, but the tablet container size is the same as before.

Do I have to change something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge of theming semantic and what I can see I wouldn't change `@tabletWidth` but I would just change `@tabletBreakpoint` and `@tabletMinimumGutter` the values you want, this should then make `@tabletWidth` in the `container.variables` use your variables to workout the width.